# Lua How to get 1st member of 2 dimensions table into new table without using loop?

Tags: lua

I am working with LUA script. I have the following data:

```
choice = {
               { 'A', '1' },
               { 'B', '2' },
               { 'C', '3' },
         }
```

I would like to get the 1st member into new table without using loop. Is these possible? Something like these:

```
first = { 'A', 'B', 'C' }
second = { '1', '2', '3' }
```

Comment: Does this count: `first = { choice[1][1], choice[2][1], choice[3][1] }` ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no quick solution. More complex solutions depends what you want to do, so if you want only select first element, you can use:

```
choice = {
               { 'A', '1' },
               { 'B', '2' },
               { 'C', '3' }
         }

first = {}
firstMeta = getmetatable(first) or {}

function firstMeta.__index(obj, i)
  return choice[i][1]
end
function firstMeta.__len(obj)
  return #choice
end
setmetatable(first, firstMeta)

f = table.pack(table.unpack(first))
```

In `f` you chave copy of first elements of choice without loops (in fact there is loop hidden in table.unpack)

Answer (score 1):

## You can't

The only way of doing that is with a loop. You can put the loop into a function so you don't see it, but it will still be there.